# How do I copy a list in an iteration?

Tags: python, list, copy, iteration

I need to make a copy of a list from a list of lists. The following code gives an error message:

```
y = list[x]
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

```
a = [[0],[1]]
for x in a:
    y = list[x]
    print y
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `x[:]` to create a copy.

Comment: my bad. how do i close my own question?

Comment: There are some intersting (and fast) answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = list[x]
```

Are you sure you aren't meaning to call the list constructor with the variable x as a parameter, instead of trying to access the element 'x' in the variable 'list'? 
As in:

```
y = list(x)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't "casting" per se, but rather "calling the list constructor".

Comment: @veiset: You know that you can edit the answer and make it a bit more precise?

Answer (score 0):

```
y=list(x)
```

The above one should work fine

Answer (score 0):

`list` is actually the type, so it makes no sense to try and get its `x` element. If you want to instantiate a list, you need to use `list(iterable)`.

Now, if you want to copy a list, the simpler solution would be to use the `copy` module.

```
import copy
a = [[0],[1]]
new_list = copy.copy(a[0])
```

Pay attention to the fact that if you want to copy an item with nested elements, you'll have to use `copy.deepcopy`.